# Run AppleScript as login item but only if it meets specific time criterion

Tags: applescript

I have this AppleScript as a "login item" (it runs every time I login), but I really just need it to run the code if I login between 5:00 AM and 11:00 pm.

I would appreciate your help to achieve this result.

```applescript
delay 60    
tell application "System Events" to keystroke " " using {option down}    
delay 1    
tell application "System Events"        
    keystroke "start"       
end tell    
tell application "System Events" to key code 36
```

Comment: No, leaving aside whatever it does, what you need to do is have it look at the clock and not do whatever it is, when you don't want it doing whatever it is.

Comment: Also, rather that popping up Spotlight/Alfred/Quicksilver/Butler/whatever and using it to launch whatever this is, why don't you, well, just launch whatever this is?

Comment: Hi Marc, I know what you mean... To be honest I'm not a programmer I kind of understand how applescript works and as you can see my script is as empiric as it looks, with this code I get the computer to run an Alfred Workflow, I think I would be able to launch it if it was an app but I couldn't come with any idea on how to make the script to laun an alfred workflow, If you know I will appreciate your help on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your *code* in an `if` *statement block* that checks the *seconds since midnight*:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set secondsSinceMidnight to time of (current date)

if secondsSinceMidnight ≥ 18000 and secondsSinceMidnight ≤ 82800 then
    
    --  # Your code goes here.
    
    
end if
```

---

**Notes:**

I assume the *code* you show in your question is either just part of it, as `keystroke` with **System Events** is sent to the front most *window*,  or you are manually bring the target *window* front most before the *code* is run.

If you place your *code* within the example `if` *statement block*, as coded, only the *code* within it will be run if it's between 5:00 AM and 11:00 PM.

Have a look at [current date](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW39) and the [date class](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCGECID) in the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1) .

Comment: Thank you! This seems just what I need, I will give a try! I Appreciate your help, I'm sorry I'm not a programmer... I would also like the script to display a notification if the "if" condition is not met... Lets say "This is not the time to run this script" do you know how can I acchieve that?

Comment: @Notrace Notracking, RE: "I would also like the script to display a notification if the "if" condition is not met... Lets say "This is not the time to run this script" do you know how can I acchieve that?" --  Yes, add an `else` _clause_ to the `if` _statement block_ with a `display notification` _command_. Have a look at **if Statements** under **Control Statements Reference** and **display notification** under **Commands Reference**  in the **AppleScript Language Guide** linked in my answer.